# Router Decompiling

Tags: firmware

I am trying to extract the squashfs filesystem of my router. [Here is firmware](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNDR3400V2/WNDR3400v2_V1.0.0.38_1.0.61.zip).

First, I unzipped the file. Next, I ran `binwalk` to get some information about the file.

```
DECIMAL     HEX         DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
58          0x3A        TRX firmware header, little endian, header size: 28 bytes,  image size: 6656000 bytes, CRC32: 0x2B1713B2 flags/version: 0x10000
86          0x56        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 65536 bytes, uncompressed size: 3614368 bytes
1282426     0x13917A    Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature,  version 3.0, size: 5367357 bytes,  853 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: Wed Aug  7 05:08:47 2013
```

I then ran `binwalk -e` to extract the contents of the file. I got three files:

```
.
├── 13917A.squashfs
├── 56
└── 56.7z
```

Running `unsquashfs` on `13917A.squashfs` failed, saying it was unable to find the magic block. This was because the file was using a non standard magic. Changing the magic to a standard one made `unsquashfs` and `file` detect it as a squashfs file system. But `unsquashfs` did not complete successfully:

```
caff@UbunutuX2:~/Netgear/test$ unsquashfs 13917A.squashfs 
Reading a different endian SQUASHFS filesystem on 13917A.squashfs
Filesystem on 13917A.squashfs is (768:0), which is a later filesystem version than I support!
```

I also tried extracting the file system by using [Jeremy Collake’s Firmware Mod Kit](https://code.google.com/p/firmware-mod-kit). This failed also:

```
caff@UbunutuX2:~/Netgear/test$ /opt/firmware-mod-kit/trunk/unsquashfs_all.sh 13917A.squashfs 
Attempting to extract SquashFS .X file system...


Trying ./src/others/squashfs-3.4-nb4/unsquashfs-lzma... Skipping others/squashfs-hg55x-bin (wrong version)...
File extraction failed!
```

How do I extract this squashfs file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After unziping the arhive, run `binwalk` with

```
binwalk -eM *.chm
```

Flag e stands for extract automatically,and M for `--matryoshka` or recursively scanning and extracting.

After a few recursive unpackings, you'll get a squashfs-root dir with what you want I guess.

For what it's worth, I tried this with binwalk version 1.2.1.

Comment: Thanks! It must be my binwalk version. The one in the Ubuntu repositories is V1.0.