# Disassembling MIPS Binaries

Tags: disassembly, mips

I am searching for security vulnerabilities in the firmware of [this router](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNDR3400V2/WNDR3400v2_V1.0.0.38_1.0.61.zip), its architecture is mips. [I have successfully unpacked the file system](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/router-decompiling). I would like to disassemble the http daemon, located at `/usr/sbin/httpd`. How can I disassemble this program and run it in `spim`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to second the suggestion of QEMU.

Craig has a post describing how to debug a MIPS binary running in QEMU using IDA:

http://www.devttys0.com/2011/09/exploiting-embedded-systems-part-3/

(you can also use GDB or another debugger speaking the GDB protocol)

Comment: All of these are such good answers I don't know which one to accept! Thank you all for helping me out :D

Comment: That's the best answer because it contains link to tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

You can give a try to [radare2](http://rada.re). It has a pretty complete support for MIPS, and provides a lot functionalities to help during the reversing process.

Comment: Can you please tell me how? I'm new to reversing.

Comment: I have been attempting to use radare2 for MIPS, and it was pretty dodgy (not analysing MIPSEL code, etc.) until I submitted several patches, so use a recent github version

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you need spim ?

I'd suggest to use [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Download) instead of spim for emulation,
[radare2](http://radare.org/y/) for disassembly  as @jvoisin mentioned and

[retargetable decompiler](http://decompiler.fit.vutbr.cz/decompilation/) for decompilation if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the disassembling part,  you may want to check **JEB** (version >= 2.3.0), which provides advanced disassembly and decompilation of MIPS 32-bit code.

The MIPS debugger is only available for Android Linux though, so you won't be able to debug your program using this tool.

There is a demo available on [PNF Software's website](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/jeb2/mips).